# Getting different output from different C compilers

Tags: c

If I'm getting different outputs on different compilers while running the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  struct s
  {
    int a;
    char b;
  } s1, s2;

  int x = sizeof(s1);
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

OUTPUT (Turbo c):

```
(int 2 + char 1 = 3)
```

I am getting 3 here.

OUTPUT (Code blocks):

```
8
```

Why is 8 is output here?

Comment: there are lot of answers reagrding `sizeof(struct)` which considers padding so it is implementation defined

Comment: @Prakash: maybe the 8 comes from 1 (char) plus 4 (int) rounded to the nearest 8.

Answer (score 0):

The size of C standard types (except `char` and its variants which are `1`) is implementation dependent as is the padding amount between structure members.

Comment: Please give me elobrate answer.